# Android Emulator Jenkins Plugin not working

Tags: android, jenkins, emulation

I am trying to use the Jenkins Android Emulator with Cloudbees and I am often experiencing this kind of output:

```
error: device offline
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:44194
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:44194 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:44194
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:44194 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:44194
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:44194
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:44194 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:44194
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:44194 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:44194
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:44194 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:44194
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:44194
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:44194 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:44194
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:44194 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:44194
[android] Timed-out after waiting 720 seconds for emulator
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:44194
[android] Stopping Android emulator
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
$ /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb kill-server
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

I am using andoird-19 as target but I have tried several.
I have also tried to reproduce the case on my local jenkins instance and it happens the same.

This gets worse when I try to load from snapshot: if I don't start from snapshot the emulator starts in the 50% of the cases, if I use the snapshots then it would always fail.

I am using emulator-arm as executable, since I read about some bugs with the 64bit version. Not sure it applies to r19 as well though.

Any idea?

Comment: I have the same issue when trying to use emulator created via Jeknins. When I'm trying to use existing emulator it simply doesn't find the image. (both issues re with v21). What is the best option to get emulator up and running?

Answer (score 3):

The Jenkins Android Emulator issues I have had are legion. Here is a checklist to help:

1) You need the --all flag for both android list and android update sdk, otherwise some packages will not be installed: ex for SDK 24

1a)`$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android list sdk --all`

1b)

```
(for i in {1..100}; do echo y; sleep 1; done) |
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,79,80,81,82,82,84,85,101,102,103,112,113,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124
```

If you get the dreaded `/home/jenkins/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-XXXX shell getprop dev.bootcomplete error: device offline` error, you are likely missing a package in step 1b

2)Ignore the dreaded `Failed to Initialize backend EGL display` error, it is a red herring

3)Be sure to use the Advanced Emulator options:

```
Emulator Options: -no-audio -gpu off
Emulator executable: emulator64-arm
Startup delay: 10  -- this *may* help
```

4)a pre-build script `${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/adb kill-server` can't hurt

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I started having the same problem after upgrading the Android Emulator plugin to 2.11.1. Downgrading to 2.10 via the plugin manager has proved itself to be an acceptable workaround for me.

Comment: Using sdk 4.2 or Android-18/Google API 18 works fine. I guess it happens only with the last version of SDK.

Comment: Hi Can you elaborate how you downgraded? I dont see such an option in my "Installed" tab

Comment: Yeah, specifying "android-18" instead of "android-19" worked fine.

Comment: Switching from 19 to 18 is not a very good solution it you need to test your app against many Android versions...

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same issue, using the Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin v2.13 with emulators running android-19 and above.

I found an open Jenkins ticket to fix the issue [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27456).

Looks like a fix would require an update to the Android Emulator Plugin. In the meantime one workaround is to use a pre-android-19 emulator - I have not had the issue on android-16, android-17 or android-18 emulators.

An alternative workaround is to try downgrading the Android Emulator Plugin to v2.10, as @zachgeek suggested.