# Android Emulator on Jenkins error: device offline

Tags: android, plugins, jenkins, adb, emulation

I have installed the Android Emulator plugin for Jenkins. I can build and test an Android-project. My Jenkins is running on an Ubuntu-server (only access with terminal). The project is pulled from Github. Now I want to use the Emulator. This is my configuration:

- Android OS version: 4.4
- Screen density: 160
- Screen resolution: 480x800
- Target ABI:armeabi-v7a

I also installed adb and did the following command:

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --no-ui
```

But it doesn't work:

```
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list 3440b28279e2e95113ce1c9499d9d881e76f6810 # timeout=10
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android list target
[android] Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk-linux
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 7767 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
[android] Starting Android emulator
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -ports 7765,7766 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
Failed to Initialize backend EGL display
Could not initialize emulated framebufferemulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:7766
connected to localhost:7766
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:7766 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device offline
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:7766
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:7766 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device offline
...
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:7766
[android] Interrupted while waiting for emulator to finish booting.
[android] Emulator was shut down before it finished booting
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:7766
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb kill-server
Archiving artifacts
Recording test results
ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver aborted due to exception
hudson.AbortException: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run? 
For example, AndroidManifest.xml is 10 min old
```

Is there someone with an explanation for this issue? Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699433/android-emulator-jenkins-plugin-not-working

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue, even when trying the commands manually.
But I could solve the issue when using ports like 5555,5556 according to that comment: [JENKINS-27456](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27456?focusedCommentId=230571&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-230571)

There is an associated pull request: [PR on github](http://httphttps://github.com/jenkinsci/android-emulator-plugin/pull/51)

I will see if I have time to get and test a build with that patch and will let you know if it solves that problem.

Comment: Still working on it (not full time). I noticed that "adb connect" returns "connected" once it has opened the socket and sent its "CNXN" request, but before receiving the "CNXN" response.
Then, if the next adb command is performed before that, it fails. But I don't know why that response sometime comes immediately and sometimes after 5-6 seconds. Investigating. I will post updates (and submit a PR if relevant) as soon as I have something interesting to report

Comment: So, I manage to have the plugin have something else than "device offline" by changing a bit the emulator plugin and adding a "Thread.sleep(10*1000)" after the adb connect command. But at that point, the emulator gets a "running" status for the bootanim and it is expecting a "stopped" status.

Comment: Doing tests manually (i.e. running manually the commands lines executed by the plugin) I noticed it takes more than 15 minutes to the emulator to reach that point.
FYI we are using the armeabi-v7a ABI on a x86-64 server. This is not suitable for us. The only option we are thinking about now is having the KVM configured on our cloud server to be able to use the x86_64 ABI.
Hope this helps